# Unable to Search On Elasticsearch from Hadoop MapReduce Program

Tags: java, hadoop, elasticsearch

I am trying to fire query on Elasticsearch through Hadoop MapReduce Program But unable to run its jar. Below is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/transport/TransportAddress
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 3 more
```

Previously i have loaded other libraries like ***common-configurations***, ***common-lang*** but i didn't faced problem that time. What changes should need to be done to work in correct way.

I have already tried building normal application and running it for elasticsearch.

After adding all required libraries in Hadoop's lib directory I am now able to search on Elasticsearch DB from the main function but gives me below error when i try to do same search from map function.

```
16/01/07 18:44:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201601011215_30692_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.client.Client
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at fragmentextractor.FragmentExtractor$FragmentExtractorMapper.is_clean(FragmentExtractor.java:163)
        at fragmentextractor.FragmentExtractor$FragmentExtractorMapper.writeToContext(FragmentExtractor.java:216)
        at fragmentextractor.FragmentExtractor$FragmentExtractorMapper.map(FragmentExtractor.java:282)
        at fragmentextractor.FragmentExtractor$FragmentExtractorMapper.map(FragmentExtractor.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

As per my knowledge it is able to search and load libraries in Parent process but when it clones, libraries can not be found in child. What are the other places to keep library files for making it successfull?

Comment: The respective jar is missing in the Mapper. Add the correct jar to the path.

Comment: I have created jar from NetBeans IDE buy adding all required jar files for it. Also i have checked with adding jars in PATH environment variable but No Success.

Comment: Just extract your `NetBeans created` jar and check whether it have the respective jar?

Comment: Yes in lib directory it has all the jars

Comment: Now my Map Reduce application is running, it is able to query elastic search from main function but shows error Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder when querying in Map or Reduce part of it. Where can i keep all jars to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got Answer for the problem. Below is the description:

You need to provide -libjars  option to hadoop jar command as

```
hadoop jar <MapReduce.jar> -libjars <jar_path1,jar_path2> argument1 argument2 ...
```

For identification of Jar in Map Reduce Part of Program as it extracts those Jars when provided through **libjars** option.

You can copy your all required Jars at HADOOP's lib directory but they wont be available when you perform operation related to external Jar. They will be available in main() function.

Comment: libjars is the preferred way, but I think using the lib directory would have worked. You would have needed to restart HDFS, though, to load the jar files

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.